# Matrox QID PCIe LP and Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, graphics-card

Does anyone know if I can use my Matrox QID PCIe LP multi-monitor card on Windows 7 x64?

Comment: FWIW : I had tried the Vista x64 and Windows 2008 x64 drivers and they don't install on Windows 7 so either my card is not working (although it is recognised) or I have to wait for Matrox.

Answer (score 2):

I emailed Matrox and this was the response:

> Thank you for contacting Matrox.
>
> The QID LP PCI card is not technically capable of driving such a demanding operating system as Windows 7.  This chip has been manufactured since 2003 and was not designed to run the way Windows 7 needs it to run.
>   The M9140 is the closest equivalent card to the QID LP PCI card.  It is a PCIe x16 graphics card with 4 outputs that can run up to 1920x1200 and has 512MB memory on board.
>   This card does have Windows 7 drivers available for it [here](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/graphics_cards/m_series/m9140lppciex16/).
>
> Please do not hesitate to get back to me if you have any further questions

Comment: Thanks for the update Jay. I guess that's the last for my QID card!

Answer (score 0):

It works in Windows Vista, therefor it is very likely to work in windows 7. If you put it in, and it doesn't work, try installing the Vista driver.

[The Matrox website](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/graphics_cards/qid_series/qidlppcie/) does not mention Windows 7 yet.

Comment: See above comment - Matrox state Windows 7 drivers for February 2010

Answer (score 0):

i have it working on windows 7 x32 by installing the server drivers. 
It only saw the monitors in windows thoughand allowed me to use 3 monitors, but not powerdesk. My guess is that powerdesk is the real problem issue, not the drivers...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has now released a HotFix to enable Windows 7 to run on these products in XDDM mode.   In order to install Windows 7 on your system with our cards, you need to follow the steps below.  This covers Windows 7, Windows 7 64Bit and WinServer 2008 R2.

To begin with please install the hotfix from Microsoft for the Operating System. This hotfix is required for the correct operation and is only available for download from the Microsoft support website:

http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=980731&kbln=en-us

Please execute the tool you receive from Microsoft after having registered.

*Subsequent to the hotfix installation,* install the Matrox device driver. The corresponding driver for your product can be found in the following links, you will need driver version 2.09.158:

For Win7
ftp://ftp.matrox.com/pub/mga/archive/2kxp_2k3_2k8/2010/xddm32_209_00_158_se_u_whql.exe

Answer (score 0):

I had no success as well with Windows 7 x64 and 2 X Matrox QID Pro cards. Only can get a total of four monitors across two cards. Should be capable of 8. Am reverting to Windows XPx64.